# rpm -qi not showing installed kernel version

Tags: integration, rpm, uname, qi

My OL 6.5 server show below in "rpm -qi":

Version     : 2.6.32
Release     : 431.el6
Source RPM: kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.src.rpm

But "uname -a" shows below kernel version:

Linux dmdroemoc01 3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 7 17:01:44 PST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

"rpm -q kernel" showing below:

kernel-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

I need to make "uname -a" ouput and "rpm -q kernel" ouput same to install microsoft integrated services. Any assistance please?

Comment: It sounds like the kernel you are running is being installed by something outside of `rpm`.

Comment: Not sure how it was installed, because it was done long back by some one else. Any way to check that?
Still how to resolve this issue and to make "uname -a" ouput and "rpm -q kernel" ouput same

Comment: Well, Assuming OL = Oracle Linux, which is a RHEL clone, means you're going to have to go back from the 3.8.x kernel you are running to the 2.6.x kernel. If that is acceptable, you can try to uninstall/reinstall the `kernel` RPM and then rebooting.

Comment: Someone has installed a later kernel outside of rpm. You can revert to what your distro provides, or attempt to find a *.rpm for the kernel (or later) that is installed. Either solution path will "work" eventually.

Comment: Assuming a RHEL clone, you can modify /etc/grub.conf to set the default kernel to the 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 by changing the default=x to the appropriate index. Then reboot. This does have the problem of what else will fail because you are no longer running the 3.8 kernel (like VMware or other users of kernel modules) and you cannot go back to the newer kernel because Microsoft Integrated Services will fail because you are no longer running the kernel version it installed agains.